# how to find memory eating programs

Tags: memory-leaks

I occasionally have the problem that after starting my kubuntu 10.04, there is apparently a program eating up my memory. After rebooting, the problem is solved. The free space that gets eaten up in a few minutes is about 12 GB. Is there a way of detecting which program that might be? 
Secondly, is that problem likely to be fixed with an update to Kubuntu 12.04?

Comment: It's also entirely possible that your free memory drops, but not due to programs' usage, but rather due to the OS caching file data.  Try showing the output of `top` here (or better yet, on [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), [superuser](http://superuser.com/), or some other place?  This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'top' command to check per-process memory consumption. You need to start the application from a terminal and once there, you could make it easier to spot the culprit by sorting the processes by the amount of memory consumed (you need to press F and then choose the exact field you want to use for sorting the processes).

By doing so and collecting some more information, you could even try to solve the problem by opening a bug so that the kubuntu developers are aware of it (in case they are not yet).

Answer (score 0):

First, I think there may be something wrong with your hardware driver.
Second, You can use the command top see the memory occupied details.
Third, if you have some experience about Linux, you can find some useful information from the /proc/meminfo directory.

That is all for to do when I was faced with the problem.

Maybe upgrade the system can solve the problem, but I am not sure.